# Should my client contribute towards mandatory equipment

Tags: billing

I will soon be starting an iOS application for a long time client. For the past year I have used an `iPhone 5` for my testing of APNS, GPS, etc.

The `iPhone 5` will **not** support the new `iOS 11` operating software, only the `iPhone 5s` and above will do so.

**Should my client contribute towards the purchase of an `iOS 11` compatible device?** An `iPhone 6+` for example.

Comment: Some feedback from the downvoter would be appreciated.

Comment: This is really the same question here: https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/what-are-legal-options-of-accessing-books-needed-for-freelance-translating -- Operating expenses are not invoiced directly to clients. They are part  of your **overhead** and factored into hourly rates. You need electricity to work... heat... a computer... a chair.. a desk.. would you expect your client to pay for those outright? (not my down vote by the way)

Comment: @Scott: I agree the question you linked id really similar in nature. But I can´t follow you rule: There are operating expenses of your business and special expenses for your clients specific projects - and then a lot of grey in between - and that is where these questions come from.

Comment: Actually there is no "grey in between" -- Either I need something regularly for multiple clients (operating tool) or I need something once for one client and will never need it again. No grey whatsoever. These questions are driven by a fear of spending money (or inability) on the business for tools people *know* or at least suspect the client should **not** be paying for. In short... a plumber doesn't charge you for his/her wrench... but they may charge you for a part *your house* and only *your house* needs. You can't ethically pass off "tools" as of they were "parts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends:

Are you offering iOS development as a regular service? Then update costs for your tools should be factored into your rate. There is nothing wrong with having different rates for different work, so if the tools are especially pricy or you don´t sell so much hours just up your rate (or try to find more work in that area)

Do you only do this upon your clients request: They should provide the specialized tools. Normally this means they will provide you one of their devices and you have to give it back at the end of your assignment.

As usual, there is some grey area in between and if your client is happy to contribute a certain amount for you, updating your iPhone (as it means he does not have to provide one of theirs) you may have a win-win.